# What is the difference between a set and a group?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory, terminology, definition

I'm new here probably  I wouldn't have a suitable way for asking suitable questions for this website really.

In group theory , I mixed between set and group in Algebra;  however, I checked both of them definition.

My question here is:

> Is set=group?

I think there are a large difference since we have set theory and group theory ? Can we say for example "set is finitely generated " like group ?

Comment: All groups are sets, but not all sets are groups. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics))

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  A group is a set with a binary operation (e.g., addition or multiplication) satisfying certain properties

Comment: To have a notion of "finitely generated" you must have a notion of a binary operation. Sets by themselves do not necessarily have this. Groups however, do.

Comment: See also [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-a-group-and-a-set).

Comment: A set is a collection of things, nothing more. It is meant to describe the things we want to talk about, e.g. $\{\,0,1,2\,\}$. But it could as well be $\{\,tree, shrubbery, coconut\,\}$. 

A group is a structure on a set. The set defines the group elements. But we also have an addition (or likewise a multiplication). E.g. $\{\,0,1,2\,\}$ has the addition $1 + 2 = 0, 2+2=1$; the remainders of a division by three. It is the structure which makes a group on the set of group elements.

Answer (score 8):

There are different ways to define what kind of object a group is, however it is never a set *alone*. It is usually described as a set *with* a binary operation (such that certain properties hold), or - to clarify the meaning of "with" - as a tuple (or pair) $(G,\circ)$ of a set and a binary operation (with properties). Often one speaks of "the group $G$" instead of "the group $(G,\circ)$", but that is an abuse of language; nevertheless it is very common if it is somehow clear what the operation has to be. When we speak of the group $\Bbb R$, we actually mean $(\Bbb R,+)$ (and not with multiplication as operation because that would not make a group)

Another way would be to say that a group is simply a *model* of the group axioms, which is a very different level of abstraction.

We *could* try to view a group not as a tuple but as a single "thing" as follows:

**Definition.** A *group* is a map $f$ with the following properties:

1. $\operatorname{dom}(f)=\operatorname{codom}(f)\times \operatorname{codom}(f)$
2. $f(f(x,y),z)=f(x,f(y,z))$ for all $x,y,z\in\operatorname{codom}(f)$
3. For every $x\in \operatorname{codom}(f)$, there exists $y\in\operatorname{codom}(f)$ such that for every $z\in\operatorname{codom}(f)$, we have $f(z,f(x,y))=z$.

I have however never encountered this view and made it up on the spot for this answer. :) It would be fun to express 2. and 3. in terms of the projections of the direct product to its factors instead of with elements. :)

Comment: So a set with an n-ary operation would not be a group. Is there a term for sets associated with n-ary operations?

Comment: @galen a set with a binary operation _also_ isn't a group; a set with a binary operation _satisfying certain properties_ is. There's no specific term for 'set with n-ary operation' because that doesn't really provide any additional structure; the reason we talk about groups as a thing unto themselves is because the contents of the group axioms provide a lot of additional structure that allows for a lot of statements 'unique' to groups.

Comment: Incidentally, I may be reading too much into this, but that 'single-thing' definition of group seems surprisingly close to the definition of a group object in category theory. :)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Yes, sorry I was speaking shorthandedly about groups by not mentioning closure, associativity, identity, and invertibility of the operation on the set.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I see that the term [n-ary group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-ary_group) is sometimes used in [universal algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_algebra).

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I'm still trying to understand category theory, though you're right that since morphisms in category theory only require identity and associativity, there's fewer constrains for those maps than for binary operations associated with groups.

Comment: @Galen those are just monoids

Answer (score 5):

A group is a set $G$ with an associative binary operation $\circ: G\times G\to G$ that is closed with respect to $\circ$ such that there exists an identity element $e\in G$ where, for any $g\in G$, there exists $g^{-1}\in G$ with $g\circ g^{-1}=e=g^{-1}\circ g$.

Consider the empty set $\varnothing$. It does not contain a single element, so, in particular, it has no identity element.

Comment: "closed" is redundant when $\circ\colon G\times G\to G$ to begin with

Comment: Indeed, @HagenvonEitzen, as is specifying that $g^{-1}$ is a two-sided inverse that is unique to $g$ (as the notation implies); nevertheless, pedagogically, it helps to include such things.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer .

Suppose you were asked to prove that a group $G_1$ is one and the same group as the group $G_2$, that is, to prove that $G_1 = G_2$.  ***It would not be enough you to prove that they have the same underlying set G***. You also would have to prove that their operations are exacly the same. So a group is a set ***with*** an operation ( satisfying definite properties) The 2 things  are necessary to define ( that is, to identify ) a group.

---

- The definition you will most often encounter is : a group is a set $G$ with a binary operation $\star$  on set $G$ such that....

> (i) the set is closed under the operation ( and this, in fact , is
>   already implied by the expression " operation on G" )
>   (ii) the operation is
>   associative
>   (iii) the operation has an identity element in G
>   (iv)
>   every eleemnt in G has an inverse ( for this operation)  in G.

And this definition will be put formally as : let $G$ be a set and let $\star$ be a binary operation on $G$ such that ... ,  the ***ordered pair $< G, \star>$*** is a group.

- This can be confusing since a binary operation on a set $G$ is supposed , officialy, to be a function from $G\times G$ to $G$ , and therefore, a relation from $G\times G$ to $G$, and consequently a set , since a relation is ( by definition) a set.

So here is the difficulty :  ***if a group is an ordered pair having a set as first element and an operation as second element, a group will be an ordered pair ... of sets...***

- But I think we can escape these difficulties in two ways

(1) First, when we say that a group is the ordered pair $<G, \star >$, the operation ( i.e. $ \star$)  is considered ***intensionnaly*** , as an entity satisfying some ***properties*** defined via some ***concepts ( associativity, identity element, inverse)***. So the ordered pair $<G, \star >$ is not really an ordered pair of sets, but rather an ordered pair with an extensonial "part" ( the set) and an intensional "part" ( the rules/concepts defining the operation).

(2) Second, it is meaningful in mathematics ( and maybe elsewhere) to adopt as a principle that

> the essence ( definition) of an entity boils down to its  identity conditions.

Now , you can totally identify and reidentify a group $G_1$ via its base set and the binary operation acting on it , in such a way that, if ever you encounter a group $G_2$ with exactly the same base set and the same binary operation , you can say for sure that $G_2 = G_1$. So it makes sense to say that the identity ( essence, definition) of $G_1$ is simply the ordered pair $< G, \star>$, and nothing deeper than that.

In symbols :

> Suppose that  $G_1 = <S_1, \star_1>$ and $G_2 = <S_2, \star_2>$ :
>
> if  $S_2 = S_1$ and $\star_2=\star_1$, then $G_2 = G_1$.

Note : this shows the usefulness of the " ordered pair" definition of a group; it allows to use the identity condition for ordered pairs  namely :

> two ordered pairs are identical just in case they have excatly the
>   same first element and the same second element.